# How do I update the kernel module for my network adapter?

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I am having troubles with my Wi-Fi adapter, it disconnects after a random amount of time and won't come back until a complete reboot.

I am suspecting this is a driver issue, so I have checked which driver is in use for it and this is how it looks :

lspci :

```
04:01.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3060 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
    Subsystem: Edimax Computer Co. RT3060 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
    Memory at fe500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: **rt2800pci**
    Kernel modules: **rt2800pci**
```

I have downloaded new drivers for the Ralink 3060 Network Adapter and I would like to load these drivers instead of what is being used now, in order to check if the problems resolves.

In the driver package there is a "RT2860STA.dat" file. any general direction for how to load that driver would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Please give us a link to the file you downloaded. You may or may not be able to compile the driver depending on your kernel version. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `uname -r`

Comment: My kernel is 4.10.0-28-generic
the supported kernels in this driver are something like 2.4 and 2.8
I guess it's time to give up on this thing...

I will try to disable power sleep for wifi adapter... hope it will work